# Is there a standard interpretation of this quantity?

Tags: reference-request, coding-theory

Define an encoding scheme by a pair of functions:

$$\mathsf{encode} : \mathcal{M}\to\mathcal{X},\quad \mathsf{decode} : \mathcal{X}\to\mathcal{M}$$

Typical examples of encoding schemes are things like error-correcting codes, encryption schemes, etc.
Define the *rate* of an encoding scheme in the standard way:

$$R = \frac{\log_2|\mathcal{M}|}{\log_2|\mathcal{X}|}$$

Let $R_0, R_1$ be the rates of two encoding schemes.
Does the quantity:

$$\frac{1 - R_0}{1 - R_0R_1}$$
have a standard interpretation?

---

*Context*: I have a way of designing encryption schemes by "plugging in" certain error-correcting codes into some template. In this framework, any encryption scheme has a "formal dual" (essentially using the dual codes in the instantiation. This requires a linearity assumption of course).
If $R_0, R_1$ are the rates of my encryption scheme instantiated by some code and its dual, I can relate the above expression to some other quantity that I have some lower bounds on.

This all might be interesting if this quantity has some standard coding-theoretic interpretation.
It seems plausible that it does, but I am not a coding theorist, and in general Googling for formula is quite difficult.
That being said, I am not especially optimistic, as I have not been able to give it some reasonable interpretation.